# 実機でアプリを動かそうとすると「No signing identity found」とエラーが出る

Tags: ios, xcode6

先ほどAppleのDeveloper登録を済ませて実機でアプリを動かそうとしたのですが、`No signing identity found`というエラーが出てしまいます。`No signing identity found`エラーが出てきたダイアログにある`Fix Issue`というボタンを押すと、今度は`Your account already has a valid certificate`というエラーが表示されます。そして`Your account already has a valid certificate`エラーが表示されているダイアログの`Revoke and Request`というボタンを押すと、`Cannot find a matching certificate to revoke`というエラーが出て、結果実機で動かすことができませんでした。xcodeのpreferenceでApple IDを確認すると、iOSの項目が「Member」になっています。これは登録はできているということなのでしょうか？ちなみにDeveloper登録は知人に招待してもらって登録しました。現在使っているXcodeのバージョンは6.1.1です。
また、iOS Developer CenterのiOS Certificates内の自分のアカウントのExpiresがチーム内で一人だけ`Pending Approval`となっています。これも原因の一つでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

実機デバッグをするためには、
・証明書の発行
・インストールしたいデバイスのUDIDの登録
・プロビジョニングプロファイルのインストール
等、いくつか手順が必要です。

「xcode 証明書」等のワードで検索すると丁寧に説明してくださっている方のサイトが見つかりますので、参考にするとうまくいくと思います。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。一度ご提示いただいた手順で試してみたいと思います。

Comment: 色々と試しているのですが、なかなかうまくいきません。。。
それで先ほど気づいたのですが、iOS Developer CenterのiOS Certificates内の自分のアカウントのExpiresが赤文字でPending Approvalとなっています。これはどこかで何かを承認しなければならないのでしょうか？

Comment: Actionにある「Approval」というボタンを押せば良いみたいです。  
参考サイト  
http://mamimume.lolipop.jp/blog/C26439914/E20101031012653/

Comment: 解決することができました！どうやら管理者に承認してもらっていなかったのが原因でした^^; すみません、お手数をおかけしました。誠にありがとうございました。